# How do I extract the value from a feathersjs promise

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I'm trying to show the count or number of a service of aka, `page.total` and I've written a little function to do it. However, the only thing that shows on the client is `[object Promise]`.

html:

```
<div id="number"></div>
```

public/app.js:

```
myservice = client.service('myservice')

function updateNumber() {
  const myNumber = myservice.find().then(page => page.total);
  document.getElementById('signups').innerHTML = myNumber;
}
myservice.on('created', updateNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` returns a promise object even when `.then` is called which I was setting as the innerHTML

There are two options, set innerHTML within the `.then` call, or use an async/await structure (now commonly supported by node.)

Option 1 (within `.then`):

```
function updateNumber() {
  myservice.find().then(page => document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = page.total);
}
```

Option 2 (async await):

```
async function updateNumber() {
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = await myservice.find().then(page => page.total);
}
```

Note: Courtesy of @steve on featherjs slack #help channel